# How to make an array key an array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm storing data to an array like this which is inside three nested loops (loops omitted):

```
$teamDetails[$k] = array(
    'side' => $json['data'][$i]['rosters'][$k]['side'],
    'gold' => $json['data'][$i]['rosters'][$k]['gold'],
    'aces' => $json['data'][$i]['rosters'][$k]['aces_earned'],
    'herokills' => $json['data'][$i]['rosters'][$k]['hero_kills'],
    'winner' => translateGame($json['data'][$i]['rosters'][$k]['winner']),
    'participants'[$j] => array(
         'work' => 'it worked',
     )
 );
```

How can make 'participants' an array with the indices coming from $j?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's easy

```
$teamDetails[$k] = array(
    'side' => $json['data'][$i]['rosters'][$k]['side'],
    'gold' => $json['data'][$i]['rosters'][$k]['gold'],
    'aces' => $json['data'][$i]['rosters'][$k]['aces_earned'],
    'herokills' => $json['data'][$i]['rosters'][$k]['hero_kills'],
    'winner' => translateGame($json['data'][$i]['rosters'][$k]['winner']),
    'participants' => array(
        $j => array(
         'work' => 'it worked',
     ))
);
```